# Pandas DateTime Format not working - python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, format

I am trying to format some dates with datetime, but for some reason it is ignoring my format call. I want day/month/Year format which is what the CSV file has the format is, but when I try this.

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', parse_dates=['Date'],
             date_parser=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Result:

[image]

Why is it what I can only assume "defaulting" to %Y-%m-%d ???

Comment: The format specifies what your input data looks like. Once it’s converted to a datetime it will be displayed YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS. You can change the display with strftime, but it’s probably best to leave it as a datetime to perform calculations

Comment: Can you specify the format of the Date column in test.csv which you are reading or please add a screenshot of the csv file. The issue is probably because of the month and day parameter interchanged.

Comment: The CSV format is D/M/Y.

Comment: Csv here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NyOUVQzNxUl-dwVPuwXiBAIHiGsMnmao

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')

formatted_dates =[]

for old_date in df['Date']:

    dt_obj = dt.datetime.strptime(old_date,'%d/%m/%Y')

    new_date = """{}/{}/{}""".format(dt_obj.day,dt_obj.month,dt_obj.year)

    formatted_dates.append(new_date)

df['Date'] = formatted_dates
```

Output:

```
18/1/2017
22/1/2017
31/1/2017
...
```

P.S. There's a bug with the parse_dates,date_parser in pd.read_csv which automatically changes the format to the YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: thanks for replying, I'm getting an error with that code

<lambda>
    date_parser=lambda x: dt.datetime.strptime(x, format='%d/%m/%Y'))
TypeError: strptime() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: @user3170725 can you share the csv through google drive, it would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, here it is

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NyOUVQzNxUl-dwVPuwXiBAIHiGsMnmao

Comment: Strange! Tried lots of different methods still the result is same as yours. Will come back to you.

Comment: Thanks! Yes very annoying. I can convert it to a string and it works, but doesn't work well for plotting.

Comment: @user3170725 please accept the answer if I was able to resolve your query. Thanks!

Comment: I tried but I don't know how, sorry I'm a noob. Oh figured it out, thanks for your help.